# Wrong cache key for SSI-subrequests with FastCGI

Tags: nginx, ssi

When I use SSI, NGinx uses the wrong cache key for the subrequest

```
fastcgi_cache_key       "$request_method $scheme://$host$uri";
```

The problem is, that it ends up in an infinite recursion, because on the main request NGinx stores the page including the SSI-element in its cache and then when it triggers the subrequest, uses this page (including the SSI-element) as result of the subrequest (and so on and so on). I thought `$uri` is exactly designed to avoid this (unlike `$request_uri`), but obviously it doesn't work.

nginx version is 1.3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly longer debug-session (the nginxs debug-logs are ... big) gave me the answer: It was not the cache-key directly, but by default the `REQUEST_URI` is set to `$request_uri` in `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`. The cache key is correct, but the request is always identical to the parents one, so the parent page is cached twice: Once for the parent-uri-key and once for the ssi-subrequest. On every subsequent call the (broken) cached values is used.

```
fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri;
```

Comment: Thank you, Internet stranger! You were not the only one!